# Merging data frame rows in R with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, rows

I have a data frame with 4 columns of data: `url ID`, `url`, `title` and `pageviews`, like this:

```
    ID          url  title pageviews
1 /12/      /url-1/ Page 1      1123
2 /13/      /url-2/ Page 2      4432
3 /13/ /url-2/?test Page 2         6
4 /14/      /url-4/ Page 4      4242
```

I spent a long time searching about how to merge the rows (pages) that have the same `ID` and sum the `pageviews`. I ended up with this code, using dplyr:

```
df_merged <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise_at(c("pageviews"), sum)
```

However, it creates another data frame with only ID and pageviews. I want to achieve a complete data frame, with `url` and `title` again. Something like this:

```
    ID          url  title pageviews
1 /12/      /url-1/ Page 1      1123
2 /13/      /url-2/ Page 2      4438
3 /14/      /url-4/ Page 4      4242
```

How can I achieve this result?

This is my data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("/12/", "/13/", "/13/", "/14/"), 
             url = c("/url-1/", "/url-2/", "/url-2/?test", "/url-4/"),
             title = c("Page 1", "Page 2", "Page 2", "Page 4"),
             pageviews = c(1123, 4432, 6, 4242))
```

Comment: `df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(pageviews))` ? Not sure how you decided to keep `/url-2/` and not `/url-2/?test` for `ID` 13.

Comment: I didn't, it was an example of what I wanted to return. But Curt F. suggested to use `first()` (great answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is like this:

```
df_merged <- 
       df %>% 
       group_by(ID, title) %>% 
       summarise(url = first(url),
                 total_pageviews = sum(pageviews)
                )
```

You need to think about how R should know that the desired output for `url` in the case of Page 2 is `/url-2/` and not `/url-2/?test` or something else.  Here, I just arbitrarily decided that the value to be put there is the `first()` value that occurs in the group.